# Processing array of objects into two strings

Tags: ruby, strings, array

I have an array of `Item` objects that each have a string `particular` and a numeric `amount`.  I want to put all `particular`s  (separated by newlines) into a single string and the same for all `amount`s.

Here's what I came up with:

```
particulars = []
amounts = []

items.each do |item|
  particulars << item.particular
  amounts << item.amount
end

particulars_string = particulars.join("\n")
amounts_string = amounts.join("\n")
```

So if

```
item1.particular = "food"
item2.particular = "drink"
item1.amount = 1000
item2.amount = 2000
```

then running the code above gives

```
particulars_string # "food\ndrink"
amounts_string # "1000\n2000"
```

which is correct.  However, I feel that the above code can be done better.  In particular, I want all the code in one loop, not the three (`each` and two `join`s) I have now.  What's a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get by with just two lines:

```
particulars_string = items.map(&:particular).join("\n")
amounts_string     = items.map(&:amount).join("\n")
```

`Enumerable#map`, which is mixed into `Array`, creates a new array from an existing array by running a block on each element and storing the result. In this case though you don't need a full block, since you just need to call a single method (`particular` or `amount`). So it basically extracts those into new arrays and then joins those arrays.

As a rule of thumb, you almost never have to "manually" map stuff from one array to another in Ruby using `each` and `<<`. Be sure to read the docs for [`Array`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html) and [`Enumerable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html) as they're full of good stuff.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I don't really like this approach — you're still doing 4 enumerations of the length of the items array, and there's duplication on 2 local variables, 2 methods, and an argument.

Comment: @coreyward True. Your use of `transpose` is more elegant than the duplication above.

Comment: @Flambino, you may be mixing me up with coreyward.  I think your solution is just fine. +1

Comment: @CarySwoveland Argh, so sorry. I was mixing you up - my mistake. But, then, _your_ use of `transpose` is more elegant :)

Answer (score 2):

If you had several attributes (particular, amount, ...), you might consider doing it this way:

```
class Items
  attr_accessor :attributes
  def initialize(*attributes)
    @attributes = attributes
  end
end

items = [Items.new('food', 1000), Items.new('drink', 2000)]

attributes_strings = items.map(&:attributes).transpose.map {|e| e.join('\n')}

puts attribute_strings
food\ndrink
1000\n2000
```

Comment: Clever.  I didn't know about transpose.

Comment: As mentioned: Nicer than my answer. However, you're assuming/adding some stuff compared to the original question where the item objects; it's not given that the objects in `items` respond to, or can feasibly be made to respond to, `attributes`. Luckily, it's not necessary. I'd shorten it to simply: `particulars_string, amounts_string = items.map {|item| [item.particular, item.amount]}.transpose.map {|a|a.join("\n")}`. Same input/result as the original with no assumptions about or additions to code outside of that in the original question.

Comment: @Flambino, I'm not sure if I understand your point about `items`. The contents of `items` is code, not data.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I just consider the objects in `items` "out of scope". All we know is that there's an array of items that each respond to `particular` and `amount`. You define your own `Item` class that responds to `attributes`, which may or may not be possible - we don't know enough about the context of OP's code. Of course you're more than welcome to suggest different approaches, but it's not necessary in this case, where it's a simple "given this array, produce two strings". And the core of your answer (map + transpose + map) is great for that even without assuming anything about the items